# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n^3 +1 )^{1/3}-n$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose I am given a infinite series as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n^3 +1 )^{1/3}-n$$ how can I tell that if it converges or diverges (by which test) , I applied D'alembert ratio test as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ ((n+1)^3 +1 )^{1/3}-n-1}{ (n^3 +1 )^{1/3}-n}$$ but test fails as limit comes out to be $1$ , so how to actually find nature?

Answer (score 12):

$$(n^3 +1 )^{1/3}-n = \frac{(n^3 +1 ) -n^3}{(n^3 +1 )^{2/3} + (n^3 +1 )^{1/3}n+n^2 }=\frac{1}{(n^3 +1 )^{2/3} + (n^3 +1 )^{1/3}n+n^2 }\le \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: It's also obvious, but necessary for the argument:  $(n^3+1)^{1/3}-n \geq 0$.

Comment: You could also say that  $n^3<n^3+1=n^3(1+1/n^3)<n^3(1+1/3 n^3)^3$     so  $n<(n^3+1)^{1/3}<n(1+1/3 n^3)=n+1/3 n^2$.  ( For $n>0$.)

Comment: @Clement C. For $n\geq 0$, we have $(n+1)^{1/3}-n\geq 0$ iff $(n^3+1)^{1/3}\geq n$ iff $n^3+1\geq n^3.$

Comment: @user254665 I know -- my comment is a nitpick, pointing out that the squeeze theorem also requires the lower bound (here, $0$).

Comment: i like picking nits too.But I thought the O.P. might benefit . If you really want to get picked, say "natural number".Half the members include 0 and half don't.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**
Using Taylor series (to the second order), that is $(1+x)^\alpha = 1+\alpha x + o(x)$ when $x\to 0$, you get
$$
(n^3+1)^{1/3} = n\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{1/3} = n\left(1+\frac{1}{3n^3} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right) = n +\frac{1}{3n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) 
$$
so that
$$
(n^3+1)^{1/3} - n \operatorname*{\sim }_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3n^2}
$$

Comment: what is o(x) ??

Comment: It is the [Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) for "little o." It means (and formalizes) "negligible compared to."

Comment: "$f(x)=o(x) $ as $x\to \infty$"  means that (for $x\ne 0$) we have $f(x)=x g(x)$ where $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=0$.

Comment: @user254665 Or, in this cas, as $x\to 0$ (everything is the same, replacing $\infty$ by $0$)

Comment: And when neither 0 nor infinity is specified it means "guess which one I mean."